# window.onscroll arrow function not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, scroll, safari

I'm trying to detect window position on scroll but the `window.onscroll = () => {}` function doesn't work in Safari, although it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
  myFunction() {
      window.onscroll = () =>{
        if(someCondition){
          ...do something
        } 
      }
  }
```

For some reason, Safari is the only browser where I can't log anything inside the window.onscroll function. I'm binding the function in the constructor and attaching it to a scroll event when the component mounts.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Are there any errors inside the console?

Comment: @BenM No, there aren't any console errors.

Comment: According the the MDN the `window` object has no `onscroll` event (although it is offered for some reason). The `document` object has the `onscroll` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script works from me on safari. Please try.

```js
document.addEventListener('scroll',()=>{
  console.log('scrolling')
});
```

```css
body {
height: 1200px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Scroll</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought window.onscroll was supported by safari, but addEventlistener did the trick.